# Formula for integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have the formula for the integral

$$\int_u^{\infty} \exp\{-ax^2-bx\}dx,   \;\;\;u\geq 0$$

It involves the error function.

But I cannot find anywhere a formula for

$$\int_0^{u} \exp\{-mx^2-kx\}dx$$

Note that I cannot use the approach $\int_0^u = \int_{0}^{\infty}-\int_u^{\infty}$
because the integrand changes when $x>u$, so $\int_{0}^{\infty}$ cannot be calculated on its own.

So I need $\int_0^u$ directly.

Any help?

Comment: I don't get why you claim that you cannot use $\int_0^{u} \exp\{-mx^2-kx\}dx = \int_0^{\infty} \exp\{-mx^2-kx\}dx -  \int_u^{\infty} \exp\{-mx^2-kx\}dx$

Comment: we can not compute the Limit, if we do not know what Kind of numbers are $$a,b$$

Comment: @Andreas I don't get it either! Thanks, that was silly, certainly I can use it so problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^u \exp \left(-k x-m x^2\right) \, dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } e^{\frac{k^2}{4 m}} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{k+2 m u}{2 \sqrt{m}}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{k}{2 \sqrt{m}}\right)\right)}{2 \sqrt{m}}$$
Hope it is useful

Comment: Thanks! Certainly it is,erfs are my friends.